# Attribute colors by row in a barplot

Tags: r, colors, stackedbarseries

I have trouble with the attributing colors in barplot to rows, they are non-existent. When I use the command:

```
barplot(data[,3:429])
```

it does give me the correct pattern in terms of height, but it is all black. I have 22 different rows (each with 427 variables), but those do not identify in my plot.

A small part of the data looks like this:

```
VT  ATC V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10 V11 V12 .... V429
1   1   0   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1
1   2   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   5   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0
```

I've tried adding colors, but it doesn't work like this:

```
barplot(data[,3:429],col=c("blue", "aliceblue","antiquewhite", "antiquewhite1","antiquewhite2","antiquewhite3", "antiquewhite4","aquamarine","aquamarine1","aquamarine2", "aquamarine3", "aquamarine4", "darkgreen", "darkgrey","darkkhaki","darkmagenta", "darkolivegreen","darkolivegreen1","darkolivegreen2","darkolivegreen3","darkolivegreen4","darkorange"))
```

The 22 colors were chosen randomly, there is no specific meaning to them.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works for me:

```
#dummy data
m <- matrix(sample(1:10,500*22,replace=TRUE),ncol=500)

#stacked bar plot with colours
barplot(m[,3:400],
        col=c("blue", "aliceblue","antiquewhite", "antiquewhite1","antiquewhite2","antiquewhite3", "antiquewhite4","aquamarine","aquamarine1","aquamarine2", "aquamarine3", "aquamarine4", "darkgreen", "darkgrey","darkkhaki","darkmagenta", "darkolivegreen","darkolivegreen1","darkolivegreen2","darkolivegreen3","darkolivegreen4","darkorange"),
        border = FALSE, space=0
        )
```

Is this what you expect to get?

[image]

Comment: yes, pretty much like that, only then with 22 colors and on the x-axis 427 values. but this is what i'm looking for. why doesn't mine work? i made sure it is also a matrix.

Comment: Set `border=FALSE` in barplot.